# Server 2003 incremental backups using ntbackup are too large

Tags: windows-server-2003, ntbackup

I have a week day nightly incremental backup that compliments my once a week full backup but even when I know very few files have not been modified since the last incremental or full backup, a substantial amount is always backed up! It seems to be always around 700 MB. Before you jump the conclusion it is my mailbox's I do exclude my exchange MDB data, here is the command and arguments:

```
START ntbackup backup "@C:\Backup Scripts\FullBackupSelection.bks" /F "G:\IncrementalBackup1.bkf" /FU /V:no /R:no /L:s /M incremental
```

**UPDATE**: FullBackupSelection.bks:

```
C:\
C:\Program Files\Exchsrvr\MDBDATA\ /Exclude
D:\
D:\Exchsvr\ /Exclude
SystemState
```

I am running MS Server 2003 for Small Business Server SP2.

Comment: Is there more to your backup selections?  It doesn't appear like you are including anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear to me if the backup selections you mention is complete.  But if I was wildly speculate based on the size of your backup I would bet that your backup selections include the SystemState.

A system state backup cannot be incremental.  It also happens to take up about about 700MB on a small domain.